# Is it possible to use React.js in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Using React-Native, I'll make Native app. But I don't know anything about it.
So, I am going to buy some books about React-Native.
If It is possible to use React.js in React-Native, then I will buy the book about React.js .

Is it possible?

ps. Do you know some links or website about React-Native? Please Share!

Comment: Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To work in react native, you absolutely need to learn the fundamentals of react first. Start here with react: https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

React-Native uses the same syntax as React.js. You *have* to use React in order to use RN, but the functions, methods and components are not the same. (There is no , no documentElement or anything else).

You should take a look at the Fabebook documentation for React & RN:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/
- https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Thank you so much!!